# how to Replace QTY from primary table to Main table in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

My  query is I want to replace MAIN TABLE QTY from Second table QTY

Find EXAMPLE excel Sheet here --> [SKU Inventory](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5xs69-03ZA_Vm9zVXpldm14UVk/edit?usp=sharing)

-- Look up SKU code  into MAIN TABLE table and find that same SKU code in to Second Table,

--If SKU code matches then Take that perticular SKU QTY (From Second Table) and display in to QTY Cell  where SKU are matches (Main Table -> QTY)

[ I have display one Example, 
GS16739 is displayed in Main tabel and it is also displayed in Second table(Both SKU are matches here), so what will be next step is, Take SKU QTY  "8" and replace that QTY in QTY Cell (cell address : B19 )]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a helper column to work out the correct values

First, find the new quantity using `VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,SecondTable,2,FALSE)
```

this will give an error if the SKU is not found. We can use this to our advantage

```
=IFERROR(*The vlookup*,B2)
```

meaning if there is an error, use B2 rather than the error value.

putting this all together gives

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,SecondTable,2,FALSE),B2)
```

once you have all the new values, you can do what you want with them